# How to edit template in Android Studio / JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, live-templates, android-log

I wonder to add changed "loge" template in the Android Studio editor to remove the last required param - Exception object.
How "loge" template result looks now:

Before the dafualt template insert:

```
public void doSmth() {
    //start write "loge" word here
}
```

After the dafualt template insert:

```
public void doSmth() {
    Log.e(TAG, "doSmth: ", );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

So to add template you have to follow several simple steps:

1. Open "Settings -> Editor -> Live templates -> AndroidLog"
   [image: Settings -> Editor -> Live templates -> AndroidLog]
2. Click the plus button, select "1. Live Template"
3. Fill the fields like I did:

   - Abbreviation: le
   - Description: Log.e(TAG, String)
   - Template text: android.util.Log.e(TAG, "$METHOD_NAME$ failed: $content$");
     [image: Fill the fields]
4. Click "Edit varables", select "methodName()" for METHOD_NAME variable
   [image: Edit varables dialog]
5. One more important thing! Define context to Java -> Statement:
   [image: Define context to Java -> Statement]
6. Click "Apply", click "OK", Enjoy your own template! :)

Official documentation is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html).

---

**Your template in work:**
[image: Your template in work]
[image]

```
public void doSmth() {
    Log.e(TAG, "doSmth failed: ");
}
```

Comment: You really did try hard on this answer. Thanks bro, +1 :D